# PHP Mailer sends received data to email

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have php script, which receives data from javascript application and sends them to email.

Here is how I get the data:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request = json_decode($postdata, true);
```

And here is how I convert variables:

```
$premiumTotal = $request['premiumTotal'];
$variant = $request['variant'];
$risksBuilding = $request['risksBuilding'];
```

When the variable is string - everything works fine.
But the last one is an Array ($risksBuilding) and in e-mail I receive the word "Array".

How can I output this variable ?

Comment: With `print_r` for example.

Comment: Without seeing your mail code, I'm guessing you may want to do something like: `$risksBuilding = implode(", ",$request['risksBuilding']);`